# Screeps - Unable to access Creep Memory

Tags: javascript, object, screeps

I'm relatively new to Screeps, and I've been working towards building my own basic AI system. However, I've run into a snag in my initial testing. I have a script which determines jobs to do, and then the creeps request the available jobs. I've been able to store the Job object into the creep's memory, but I cannot recall it later.

I can confirm in the Memory tab that all of the information is there, and stored correctly, but when I try to access it, I only ever get `undefined`.

[image: This is what the memory looks like once it's set]

I create my jobs using this template function:

```
jobFactory: function()
    {
        // Generates a blank JOB template
        var job = {
            'id': null,     // id of job will double as id of the target 
                                     (ie. a energy source id)
            'type': null,   // used to classify job tickets to some extent
            'spots': 0,     // total # of creeps that can be assigned to this
            'workers': []   // current # and IDs of creeps assigned
        };
        return job;
    },
```

Then I'm able to store it just fine with:
`creep.memory.job = job;`

How I'm trying to access it is:
`console.log("Creep job: " + creep.memory.job);`

I've compared it with the game tutorial, and for the life of me I can't seem to figure out why I can't access the object from the memory.

Comment: Try to write something like this in the console:

     JSON.stringify(Game.creeps.Liam.memory.job)

Answer (score 0):

I added these two lines to the begining of one of my role modules:

```
creep.memory.job = { foo: "hello", bar: 42};
console.log("Foo: " + creep.memory.job);
```

The output is: `Foo: [object Object]`

If I instead use `console.log("Foo: " + creep.memory.job.foo);`, then the output is `Foo: hello`.

I know that does not explain the `undefined`, but I wanted to clarify what you should expect to see.

Another thing to be sure of, is that the variable `creep` is what you think it is. Double check with `console.log(creep.name);` immediatly before `console.log("Creep job: " + creep.memory.job);`.

If none of this helps, more code and more context will be useful. (I am not sure exactly where you are trying to execute which pieces of code.) Also, what is the exact output? Are you getting `Creep job: undefined` or just `undefined`?